# Groovy - List Sum

Tags: groovy

I am trying to sum all the numbers in the range (0 to 9) which can be divided by 3 or 5.

**Approach 1:**

```
    def result = (0..9).findAll { 
        (it % 3 == 0 || it % 5 == 0)
    }.sum()
    println result
```

Prints 23 which is as expected.

**Approach 2:**  Same as above. But am trying to ignore a temp variable `result` & print directly.

```
    println (0..9).findAll {
        (it % 3 == 0 || it % 5 == 0)
    }.sum()
```

Prints `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

What is going on here? Why is showing the entire list instead of the sum in the Approach 2.

**Approach 3:**  Same as approach 2. Printing it directly. But moved the range to a variable.

```
    def lst = 0..9
    println lst.findAll {
        (it % 3 == 0 || it % 5 == 0)
    }.sum()
```

Prints 23 again.

Does Groovy expect me to have a temp variable always :( ??

Answer (score 5):

The groovy parser thinks you're doing

```
println (0..9)
```

And then doing the rest of it to the result of the println

Just give the parser a helping hand with an outer set of parentheses

```
println( (0..9).findAll {
    (it % 3 == 0 || it % 5 == 0)
}.sum() )
```

Comment: `The groovy parser thinks you're doing println (0..9)`. Yes, but why?

Comment: I tried that already by wrapping everything with a ( ). It works. But my question is - why does groovy not think so as you say whn  i give println lst.findAll....  So Groovy expects a variable to work on a range/list?

Comment: Don't understand. It's the brackets. (0..9) looks like a function call